# how to post something in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my `routes` I wrote a route like this:

```
Route::post('cp/admin/checkUserPassLogin','Panel\AdminController@checkUserPassLogin');
```

in my view :

```
$.post("{{URL::to('/')}}/cp/admin/checkUserPassLogin", {username:email,pass:pass}, function (data) {


                console.log(data);
```

but my console doesn't return anything !

Comment: Do you see any errors on the server? Have you checked your network tab to see what the response is?

Answer (score 1):

### Your Issues

- You are not showing what the controller does.
- Your post URL may be bad

### Try This

```
Route::post('cp/admin/checkUserPassLogin', 'Panel\AdminController@checkUserPassLogin');
```

-

```
public function checkUserPassLogin(Request $request) {
    return response('POST RESPONSE');
}
```

-

```
$.post("{{ url('/cp/admin/checkUserPassLogin') }},
    {username:email,pass:pass}, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
});
```

### Edit

- make sure jQuery is loading
- make sure the $.post URL is proper

  - may get a bad URL if `config/app.php` settings are not the same as current server (i.e. domain, port)
  - [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) will only work on same domain requests.

**I think your `$.post()` data is invalid JSON. The variables must have a value. Try this:**

```
$.post("/cp/admin/checkUserPassLogin",
    {
        username: 'test@example.com',
        pass: 'password'
    },
    function (data) {
        console.log('jQuery.post Success:');
        console.log(data);
    }
)
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('jQuery.post Error:');
    console.log(errorThrown);
})
;
```

-

```
public function checkUserPassLogin(Request $request) {

    return response()->json($request->all());

}
```

Comment: my codes like you.but `console.log(data);` doesn't return anything.